# jQuery toggleClass on only div element

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with a `href` to another site in it. I want to add a class to the `div` which would style it a bit different, however, when the `href` is clicked, the class I want to add only to the `div` gets added. Is there a way I can have the class only added when the div is clicked?

HTML:

```
<div class="preview">
    <img src="some-image.jpg">
    <a href="http://external-link.com">Link to somewhere</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.preview').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('preview-active');
});
```

Comment: Is that a plugin like coffeescript or a typo? `$('.preview').click: function` looks wrong.

Comment: He `:` when he shoulda `(`.

Comment: The `href` is not clicked. The `href` is *never* clicked, the anchor element, the `<a>` is, and can be, clicked, but the `href` is simply a *property* of the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like below. This checks the event's target (`e.target`) to see if you should carry on...

```
$('.preview').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if(!$target.is('a')) {
    alert('You did not click the link');
  } else {
    alert('You did click the link');
  }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/qebos/1/edit

Comment: So when I click on the link the class doesn't get added, which is what I'm looking for... however, when I click the image the class doesn't get added either. How would I make is so everything except the link is clickable? Would I just at it `.preview img`?

Comment: Here goes a fiddle of it working and I updated my answer: http://jsbin.com/qebos/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Bill Criswell, thank you so much. +1 for the Vanilla Ice pic... lol!

Answer (score 0):

You would need add it to the parent element (`<div>`)...

`$(this).parent().toggleClass('preview-active');`